# Adverb for "always correct"

Tags: single-word-requests, adverbs

Is there an adverb for expressing that something is always done in a correct manner?

Examples that I'd like to apply this to:

- "He always does this correctly" -> "He does this ***-ly".
- "This cannot always be done correctly" -> "This cannot be done ***-ly"

Comment: **[Repeatably](http://wikidiff.com/repeatedly/repeatably)** may come close to your need.

Comment: You are looking for a single-word adverb meaning *always* and *correctly*, aren't you?

Comment: @Davo Thanks for the suggestion. However, "repeatably" only expresses that something is capable of being repeated, not repeated *correctly*. The way I see to use it would be along the lines of "He does this repeatably correctly". I'd rather use "He always does this correctly" than two adverbs in a series..

Comment: @mahmudkoya I'm actually looking for a single-word adverd meaning *always correctly*.

Comment: No one has suggested accurately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [this comment from user Mahmud Koya](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/387467/adverb-for-always-correct/387474#comment913047_387467), I had the idea of searching for "always correctly" in a [reverse dictionary](http://reversedictionary.org/wordsfor/always%20correctly). This led me to [**unfailingly**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/unfailingly).

Comment: Surely this still only means that he never fails to do the thing, without specifying the standard to which he does it? Like 'consistently' it still requires the comparative element of doing it perfectly.

Comment: @Spagirl: Thank you, I believe you managed to pinpoint exactly my other cause of contempt with this choice. However, I now noticed that the question is about expressing that something is always done in *a correct manner*. I'm not sure if *correct* can be broken down into different "degrees of correctness". I presume something is either correct or it isn't, therefore rendering the need to specify the standard to which the agent does the action unsolicited.

Answer (score 2):

Consider ***consistently***.

> "He always does this correctly" -> "He does this ***consistent***-ly".
>   "This cannot
>   always be done correctly" -> "This cannot be done ***consistent***-ly"

ODO:

> **[consistently](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/consistently)**
>   *ADVERB*
>
> **1** In every case or on every occasion; invariably.
>   ‘the vehicle consistently outperforms some of the best competitors’
>
> **[consistent](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/consistent)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **1** **Acting or done in the same way over time, especially so as to be** fair or **accurate**.
>   ‘the parents are being consistent and
>   firm in their reactions’

Comment: Thank you for your time. However, if I understand the definition correctly, "He does this consistently" means only that the agent does the action in every case or on every occasion, thus not expressing the fact that the action is done in a correct manner. Consider the sentences "He always ties his shoes correctly" and "He ties his shoes consistently"; I believe these convey slightly different meanings.

Comment: +1. Also if the original sentence could be slightly modified, a more concise version could be *he succeeds consistently*, or *This cannot consistently succeed*.

Answer (score 2):

The closest match I can think of is **infallibly**.

The [OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/infallible) describes 'infallible' (the adjective form of the word) as:

> 'Incapable of making mistakes or being wrong'

and

> 'Never failing; always effective'.

I think it carries the meaning of 'always correct' without too many problems. So in the OP's two sentences, we'd have:

> 'He does this infallibly'.

and

> 'This cannot be done infallibly'.

Comment: Is there [any difference](http://wikidiff.com/unfailingly/infallibly) between your answer and mine?

Comment: @JLaguna: There *is* a difference, I think, between infallibly and unfailingly, but it's very slight and subtle. *Infallibly* has the sense of being incapable of error (ie, doing something perfectly). *Unfailingly* seems to focus more on the unflagging and never-ending nature of whatever task is being repeated. I think a lot depends on context, and whether you would prefer to focus more on the correctness (ie the infallibly option) or the repetition (ie the 'unfailingly' option).

Comment: I see. Thank you for the explanation, I think I agree with you.

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a single-word adverb precisely having the meaning *always correctly*. But I can suggest a few adverbs closer to your search.

Flawlessly, seamlessly, accurately or precisely.

> **[flawless](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/flawless)** (en.oxforddictionaries.com) adjective
>
> *Without any imperfections or defects; perfect.*

**flawlessly (adverb)**

> **[seamless](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seamless)** (Merriam-Webster)
>
> b :  **perfect, flawless**
>
> *a seamless performance*

**seamlessly  (adverb**)

> **[accurately](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/accurately)** (en.oxforddictionaries.com) adverb
>
> ***In a way that is correct in all details; exactly.***
>
> ***[precisely](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/precisely)*** adverb
>
> ***in exact terms; without vagueness.***
>
> *"the guidelines are precisely defined"*
>
> ***exactly*** (used to emphasize the complete accuracy or truth of a statement).

Answer (score 0):

accurately as in:

Merriam Webster:

Definition of accurate
1
:  **free from error** especially as the result of care an accurate diagnosis
2
:  **conforming exactly to truth or to a standard** :  exact providing accurate color
3
:  able to give an accurate result an accurate gauge

to do something accurately.

But it only for things like doing a project or describing something.